# Android app build failing with gradle

Tags: android, build, build.gradle

I am the error when trying to build an existing project in android studio 2.2.3

**FIRST ERROR**
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
>   The android gradle plugin version 2.3.0-beta1 is too old, please update to the latest version.
>   To override this check from the command line please set the ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "38489eef475e39c9974f03c995d6529764875fa8"

**Next step** - Update latest build version

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.5.0-alpha-preview-01'

**SECOND error**

Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.registerTransform(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Action;)V'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows Environment, open System properties(right click My Computer), set(add if not there) environment variable **ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE**, and set the value to 38489eef475e39c9974f03c995d6529764875fa8 or whatever coming on message log.

Restart your Android studio, project should build without any issues.

I was also facing this Daily Override issue after upgrading Repository it is gone now so also update your Android Studio.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! now I am getting following error. Error:(7, 1) Execution failed for null.
> Unable to find signing.gradle, please replace Android buildTypes > signing configs with your own configuration.

Comment: looks like you are missing signing information in your app gradle file..please share your app gradle file

Comment: I am trying to run the application code https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid, and the build is failing at //if (file('signing.gradle').exists()) {
//    apply from: 'signing.gradle'
//}else{
//    throw new TaskExecutionException(null, new Exception("Unable to find signing.gradle, please replace Android buildTypes > signing configs with your own configuration."));
//}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original question, you are unlikely to want to use 2.5 at this point. We only released 2.5 alpha preview primarily for advanced early adopters to try at this point.

The reason you were getting the error is because preview versions of the Android Gradle plugin are time-bombed. You just need to update to a newer version. Simply change your line to:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-rc1'

Once we publish the stable version, you can then change to:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

The stable version won't be time-bombed. Hope it helps.

If you haven't updated the Gradle version, you will need to update it to 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/2-5-alpha-gradle-plugin/trying-gradle-plugin-2-5 when you are using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.5.0-alpha-preview-01`